# Bolas são preenchidas de acordo com o status da página

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário onde tenho três páginas e consequentemente três bolinhas superiores, cada uma representando uma página. A lógica do formulário já está concluída onde cada página é mostrada de acordo com a variável parâmetro com um data-ng-show. Preciso que de acordo com a página que o usuário esteja preenchendo a bolinha correspondente troque o background. Consegui fazer as bolinhas com CSS e colocar os ícones correspondentes nelas porém não estou conseguindo deixa-lo responsivo(preciso que ele seja responsivo, to usando o Bootstrap) e ainda preciso de uma barra ligando essas três bolinhas que vai preenchendo de acordo com a página.

Segue o código que cheguei:

```css
.bola {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bola"><img class="img" src="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/images/imgsStatus/medicamento.png"></div>
```

[image: Imagem de como está no formulário]

Comment: Poderia fazer com JavaScript, mas o que identifica uma página da outra? O JavaScript precisaria saber em que página está para aplicar alterações.

Comment: Sim poderia, é q assim imaginei q fosse mais fácil... É uma variavel com valor de 1 a 3 correspondente a cada pagina...